# E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR in Android Kitkat and below

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Edit : I forgot to tell, i already try to make a breakpoint on the onRefreshToken and make a `Log` in that function, but when i start the apps, none of them is running (the breakpoint doesn't start, and the `Log` doesnt showing in AS's console log). So IMO its pure that the service itself doesn't start.

---

I make a code where my apps gonna show a notification if there is a data incoming in onMessageReceived. **Its can run well, no problem at all, until i try it in Android Jelly Bean**.

The notification doesn't showing (**i am sure the notification is sent, because the other non JellyBean device is show the notification at the same time.**) and then i **trying it in KitKat Device, the result is same**.

I then try to debug it and no error showing in Android Studio ( I bet because the device got Chinese rom and doesn't have Google play service built in).

Later i change my method and try it in Emulator, and the `E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR` is showing. I already try it in emulator that have KitKat and JellyBean image installed, the result is same, the same message appear.

This is my code:

**AndroidManifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.appname">

///Some activity and meta data here

    <service
        android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIdService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:ignore="ExportedService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:ignore="ExportedService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</manifest>
```

**MyFirebaseInstanceIdService**

```
class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService : FirebaseInstanceIdService() {
    val TAG = "PushNotifService"
    lateinit var name: String

    override fun onTokenRefresh() {
        val token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().token
    }
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService**

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    private val session = SessionManagement(this)

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.data != null){
            val data = remoteMessage.data
            val title = data["title"]
            val body = data["body"]
            showNotification(title, body)
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    override fun onNewToken(token: String?) {
        session.updateFCMToken(token)
    }

    fun subscribeTopic(topic: String?){

//the topic in here is a param send by other activity when the apps lunch 

FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(topic).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
            } else {
            }
        }
    }

//This sendMessageTrainer() is called and run from other activity

    fun sendMessageTrainer(){
        val contentType = "application/json"
        val authorizationKey = ServerHelper.FCMServerKey
        val data = "{\"to\": \"/topics/sometopic\",\"data\": {\"title\":\"Request Update\",\"body\":\"New Request.\"}}"
        Fuel.post(ServerHelper.FCMServer).header("Content-Type" to contentType, "Authorization" to "key=$authorizationKey").body(data).responseJson{
            _, _, result ->
            result.failure {
                sendMessageTrainer()
            }
            result.success {
            }
        }
    }


//showNotification() is run if there is a new data/notification from onMessageReceived 

    private fun showNotification(title: String?, body: String?) {
        val intent = Intent(this, LauncherActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        val channelName = getString(R.string.app_name)
        val channelID = "default"
        val alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notifyID = 1
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(alarmSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build()
        when {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {
                val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
                val mChannel = NotificationChannel(channelID, channelName, importance)
                val mNotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
                mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
                mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID , notification)
            }
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.N -> {
                val mNotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
                mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, notification)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Thanks and regards,**

**vl14b**

Comment: did you fix it bro???